# C# printformat placeholders

Tags: c#, placeholder

can anyone give me a list of the printFormat placeholders in C#?
somewhere deep in MSDN one exists, and I even found it, but it's really troublesome and not really convenient.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) wrote one for Refcardz - [Core .NET](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/coredotnet)

Answer (score 1):

is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx) what you are looking for? Look under the numeric form and datetime format sections.